# spark database connections: commit?

Tags: commit, apache-spark-sql

I have been thinking about spark and database connections for a while, and I wonder if anyone out there knows how to send a commit to a database through spark? E.g.: I have just opened up a jdbc connection and queried some db: what happens to the connection then - I take it that it does not get dropped automatically.

Right now I'm thinking about just sending a `commit` query somehow...?

Cheers!